# How to add include directories to a swig cmake target without adding them globally?

Tags: c++, cmake, include, swig, include-path

How do you specify include_directories for a swig target in cmake? I see that to add a swig target you do:

```
swig_add_library(swg_target
        TYPE STATIC
        LANGUAGE python
        SOURCES swg_src_files.i swg_src_files.h swg_src_files.cpp
)
```

but following this with the usual

```
target_include_directories(swg_target PUBLIC ".../include")
```

does not work (i.e. seems to do precisely nothing) and instead I need to put

```
include_directories(".../include")
```

**before** the call to `swig_add_library`. Is there a way to add include directories to a swig target without adding these directories globally for every target?

Comment: If the `target_include_directories` doesn't work, you could (as a workaround) add a new `INTERFACE` library, link that against the swig target and use `target_include_directories` with this "helper" target. Client code then links against the new `INTERFACE` library, not the swig target directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the hood, `swig_add_library` must eventually invoke `add_library` and set some properties, but there is something curious in the documentation:

> Target library properties can be set to apply same configuration to all SWIG input files.
>
> `SWIG_USE_TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`
> If set to TRUE, contents of target property INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES will be forwarded to SWIG compiler. If set to FALSE or not defined, target property INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES will be ignored. This behavior can be overridden by specifying source property USE_TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.

Thus, in order to use `target_include_directories`, but you must also set the above property on your target. It was added in CMake 3.13, if I read the Git history correctly.